# Lambda Event querystring parameters are undefined ? What needs to be configured?

Tags: lambda, query-string, serverless-framework

Hi I have Lambda ApiGateway Endpoint for a GET Request.
I am making the GET Request with querystring parameters and it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Here is how I made the call from client:

```
SearchEvents(term: string): Observable<Event[]> {
  const query = `term=${term}`;
  const options = {
    params: new HttpParams({
       fromString: query
    })
  };
  let url = this.SERVICE_URL + 'event/search';
  console.log('search url', url);
  return this.http.get<Event[]>(url, options)
     .pipe(map((val) => val.map((i) => new Event(i))));
```

}

Whenever I call this endpoint I can not get the querystring parameters from the event.

This is the handler:

```
export const SearchEvents: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, _context) => {

try {
    console.log('event', event);
    let parameters = event.queryStringParameters;
    console.log('queryString', parameters);
    if (parameters && parameters.hasOwnProperty('term')) {
      let eventService = new EventService(
        process.env.REGION,
        process.env.STAGE
      );
      let res = await eventService.SearchEvents(parameters.term);
      if (res.isError()) {
        return ApiGatewayResponseService.Error(res.error);
      }
      return ApiGatewayResponseService.Success(res.data);
    } else {
      return ApiGatewayResponseService.BadRequest('Missing search term');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return ApiGatewayResponseService.Error(e);
  }
};
```

I am using Serverless Framework for deployment and this the function set up:

```
SearchEvents:
handler: src/event-handlers/EventController.SearchEvents
events:
- http:
    method: get
    path: /event/search
    request:
      parameters:
        querystrings:
          term: true
```

Anyway for deployed version of the Lambda I can not get the QueryString parameters from the event, but I can get them when I run my service locally with serverless-offline

Comment: Can you verify this route exists in api gateway in web console?

Comment: Try removing the `request` in your `http` in your `serverless.yml`.

Comment: @jellycsc Yes this route exists in the console and when I Test the endpoint with query strings that AWS Console provides it works good there, accessing the route "/event/search?term=test". When I try from Postman doesn't work. It access the handler but can't find event.queryStringParameters.

Comment: @NoelLlevares I have tried that as well